# sas sum based on row by row and flag

Tags: sas, row

I have a data like below

```
laonno      debit            childno  credit

1234       4162.98          .             .

1234        0.02               .             .

.                  .                 1234       1387.66

.                  .                 1234       1387.66

.                  .                 1234       1387.66
```

I need output as when the debit sum is equals to credit sum then for those observations flag should be generated as mentioned below

```
laonno      debit            childno  credit               flag

1234       4162.98          .             .                   matched

1234        0.02               .             .                      N

.                  .                 1234       1387.66       matched

.                  .                 1234       1387.66       matched

.                  .                 1234       1387.66       matched
```

The data rows  will be dynamic but when the sum of debit matches credit then the following flag should be as "MATCHED" .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Some question for you to clear you question: How do you define "MATCHED", oh, it is `4162.98 = 3 * 1387.66`. may `4162.97 + 0.01 = 3 * 1387.66` be another anwser?(if there are 4162.97 and 0.01)

Comment: then the sum of both observations with  4162.97 and 0.01 amounts should get flag as matched as combination of both equal to credit amount

Comment: So are you asking a solution for: sum of any number from `debit` equals to sum of any number from `credit`? It could be done in simple loop way but does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is representative, here is one way

```
data want (drop=s);
    if _N_ = 1 then do;
        dcl hash h ();
        h.definekey ('childno');
        h.definedata ('s');
        h.definedone ();

        dcl hash hh ();
        hh.definekey ('laonno');
        hh.definedone ();
        
        do until (lr);
            set yy(where=(childno)) end=lr;
            if h.find() ne 0 then s = credit;
            else                  s = sum(s, credit);
            h.replace();
        end;

    end;

    set yy;
    s = .;

    if h.find(key : laonno) = 0 & round(s, .001) = debit then do;
        flag = 'Matched';
        hh.ref();
    end;
    else flag = 'N';

    if hh.check(key : childno) = 0 then flag = 'Matched';

run;
```